# How to use _Layout.cshtml design across the application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a solution where I want consistent design across the solution.
My design is in _Layout.cshtml and I want to use the same design in different page but I am not getting the same design.
i supplied `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` in other page and thought it would work but no luck.
Please help and guide me what I am missing here.

This the page Where I want to use the design

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>      
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
     <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="page-top">
    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
                </div>
               </a>
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Employees")">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">
           
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Attendace</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Attendace:</h6>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
                    <span>Reports</span>
                </a>              
            </li>
 
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">
            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->
        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">
                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">
                    <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <!-- Topbar Search -->
                    <form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                
                </nav>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->
                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Page Heading -->
                    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Dashboard</h1>
                        <a href="#" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-download fa-sm text-white-50"></i> Generate Report</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Content Row -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Earnings (Monthly) Card Example -->
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                            <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                                        <div class="container body-content">
                                            @RenderBody()
                                            <hr />
                                        </div>
                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
    </div>
   
    </div>
   

    <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
        <div class="container my-auto">
            <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">              
                <span>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Sikh Limited</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- End of Footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>  

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Page level plugins -->
    <script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
    <script src="js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you use the layout? Do you just get the page without the layout added or do you get an error? Have you tried removing the `~` from the layout path?

Comment: @Charleh - I am getting the page without layout design.I tried removing `~` as well but no luck. Can you please guide me.

Comment: It looks fine to me, what do your routes/area definitions look like?

Comment: @Charleh - I am creating CRUD application. I am using Index to list all the records. My route looks like `routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Employees", action = "Index", id = lParameter.Optional }
            );`